# Is there a three-way or five-way version of Wilson Score?

Tags: distributions, ranking

Wilson Score can be used in online rating systems, but it is based on a binomial distribution which, according to Wikipedia's [Binomial proportion confidence interval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval), is when there are only two outcomes to an experiment.

A rating system I have for a project has three outcomes. Many people have systems that have 0-5 stars, making 5 or 6 outcomes.

How can I use this equation in the case of a multiplicity of outcomes?

Is there such a thing as a trinomial or pentanomial distribution?

Answer (score 1):

There are indeed such things as "trinomial" and so on, though usually beyond "binomial" or "trinomial" people generally just say "multinomial".

See Wikipedia on the [Multinomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution).

However, if you're trying to construct an interval for the probability of a single outcome (e.g. the probability of rolling a 6 on a die that may not be fair), it doesn't matter whether - or how - you split up "not-6" outcomes, a confidence interval for the probability of a 6 is the same.

Which is to say, you can still use binomial proportion confidence intervals for the probability of a single outcome.

Where things may get more complicated would be where you wanted some kind of joint interval for two outcomes (but it's still not especially onerous even so).

As such, the lower bound of a Wilson score interval should be about as reasonable a choice for ratings when there are three or five or six outcomes as when there are two. [Equally, lower bounds for other binomial intervals might also be used.]

Comment: Well there is only one outcome, but there are choices: people can rate things to be "Awesome" "good" or "needs work" ... maybe that clarifies at what I'm angling.

Comment: I was referring to the number of *possible* outcomes, just as you did when you said "*in the case of a multiplicity of outcomes*" and "*has three outcomes*" -- which is to say, my response applies to the situation you're describing. Your question and my answer both discuss the case of assuming a set of mutually exclusive outcomes among which a single choice is made (independently and with unchanging probabilities) for each observation.

Comment: so basically you are saying that for each possible outcome there can be a score or "interval" (the score is figured out just using the lower bound) and  I can combine them to make meaningful sorts?  Yes, your assumption is correct in that the outcomes do not "overlap" but they do fit snugly/ flush.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "*I can combine them to make meaningful sorts*"

Comment: Allow me to elaborate, I'm using the Wilson Score because people vote/rank content in a system I'm building.  Since there is uncertainty with a small number of votes/rankings, it's important to weigh the score using this information, which is what makes the Wilson Score useful and appealing.  However, my system is not a binary (up vote down vote) system but is trinary (double up, up, down)  and I'd like to understand how to apply this to the wilson score so that I get useful values -- imagine all the posts on stats.se sorted in this way.  That's where "sorts" comes in.

Comment: It's still not clear what you're combining. The Wilson score will give you a lower bound on the estimated proportion in each category. It's also not clear what you mean by "useful values" -- your clarification left unexplained exactly the same things I didn't follow in my previous comment.  What are you planning to do with the three lower bounds, and why? What are you trying to make it do? What makes something "useful" or "meaningful" for your purposes?

Comment: Please check out http://www.evanmiller.org/how-not-to-sort-by-average-rating.html -- basically he shows how if you are going to arrange objects on the criteria of pos/neg score (up votes down votes) then one should use the wilson score and arrange them in a descending order, since wilson score takes into account uncertainty.  I am trying to use the wilson score but in an application where there are 3 types of votes, not just two.  I think it would be helpful to be able to generalize it to N many types of votes -- that is my specific question.

Comment: The main issue was your intent with "combine", but I see now -- you're simply re-asking the question. As I've said, there's no reason you can't use the same approach (compare the lower bound of the WIlson interval, or other intervals for a binomial proportion) for more than two categories.

Comment: Ohh thank you. I was thinking for some reason the score would be a number like 80 or 500 but I suspect now that they must fall in the range of [0..1] and therefore there's no need to "combine" them as I was thinking was the case.

Comment: Yes, the Wilson interval lies entirely in [0,1]; the lower bound is simply the lower end of a CI for a proportion. Some other binomial intervals can creep just outside that range but most stay inside it. But for your problem you *might* have a reason to try to combine the different rating categories into some overall score, so I wasn't sure what you might do with them.